# React Native: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent

Tags: android, react-native, crash

My React Native app-release.apk is crashing when I opened it. The app-debug.apk is working absolutely fine. So, I run this command `adb logact <my app package name>:V *:S`. After running this command I opened the app and in the console I got this message.

Can anyone tell what might be the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by updating the dependencies which are installed in my app. Those dependencies are using deprecated APIs, so after I updated the dependencies to the latest ones, my application runs perfectly.